# Why getline output is changed depending on is I calling append or not

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I want to make function that will duplicate selection to end of selection

```
function! DuplicateBlock() "{{{
  let lines = getline(line('v'), line('.'))
  echo lines
  call append(line('.'), lines)
endfunction "}}}
vnoremap <C-D> :call DuplicateBlock()<CR>
```

then I select with V content of this function and press , `echo lines` output:

```
['  let lines = getline(line('v'), line('.'))']
['  let lines = getline(line('v'), line('.'))']
['  let lines = getline(line('v'), line('.'))']
```

if I comment append line, output will be

```
['  let lines = getline(line('v'), line('.'))']
['  echo lines']
['  call append(line('.'), lines)']
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`:help append()`**](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#append())

---

```
append({lnum}, {expr})                                  append()
```

> **When {expr} is a List: Append each item of the List as a 
>    text line below line {lnum} in the current buffer.**

```
                Otherwise append {expr} as one text line below line {lnum} in
                the current buffer.
```

By pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> function `DuplicateBlock()` will of course start treating first line of visual selection and when excuting `append(line('.'), lines)` it will add that line  (added to the list) after the current line (which is actually a duplication of line treated). The second invocation of function will do the same thing for the line previously added and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:copy`/`:t` command instead.

```
:copy '>
```

or as a mapping:

```
xnoremap <C-D> :copy '><CR>
```

If you want your cursor at the top of the freshly duplicated block you can do:

```
xnoremap <C-D> :copy '><CR>'[
```

For more help see:

```
:h :copy
:h marks
:h '>
:h '[
```

Comment: Actually this pretty neat, better that [one that I use](https://github.com/BjornMelgaard/dotfiles/blob/3c2f77799ff37f4774ee0977a0898802db4d01c8/nvim/plugin/misc.vim#L41)